# Error while attempting to use "cordova build" on an Android project with sub-project references

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

I just upgraded my Apache Cordova project to Cordova 3.2 and changed everything to a cordova CLI project at the same time. It was all working fine until, in my Android app, I added a reference to another, third-party project. The Android app still works fine with that sub-project, however, now when I try to run "cordova build" from the command line I get the following error:

```
Preparing android project
Compiling app on platform "android" via command "/<path-to-my-cordova-project>/platforms/android/cordova/build" 
[Error: An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing "ant clean -f /<path-to-my-cordova-project>/platforms/android/build.xml": 
BUILD FAILED
/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:471: Invalid file: /<path-to-my-android-sub-project>/build.xml
```

The Android sub-project uses maven, rather than ant, so there is no build.xml file. But Cordova wants one to exist, for some reason… I tried placing a dummy build.xml file in the sub-project, but Cordova doesn't like that either.

I know that typically Cordova projects don't have sub-projects, since all of the app code is typically just html/javascript/css.  So, is the concept of a sub-project simply something that the Cordova CLI doesn't support yet?  Is there a way I can get the CLI to just ignore the sub-project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`android update project`](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html) command to create a `build.xml` file that cordova's ant will like. If the subproject has a lot of dependencies that maven resolves, then you may end up with a multi step build where you resolve the dependencies of the subproject first then do the cordova build.

More details about the sub project would help.

Comment: Thank you! That got me past the above error, and now it looks like I just have some jar and/or build-path issues.  For some reason, the main project can't find the classes defined in the sub-project (https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) when building from Ant...

Comment: @Troy you probably just need to tell the main project that SlidingMenu is a library project. You do that in the main project's `project.properties` file with a line that looks something like this: `android.library.reference.1=path/to/SlidingMenu/library`